# Is there an OSX utility to operate an MBP (Mountain Lion) in clamshell mode?

Tags: macos

I can see that there are utilities to keep an MBP awake (such as 'Caffeine'), but would you know if it's possilbe to operate an MBP in clamshell mode without the monitor being connected?

Comment: Perhaps try http://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best utility to do this, in my experience, is [InsomniaX](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/22211/insomniax).

Note that in the above link, there are a number of suggested alternatives under 'Similar Software' such as 'No Sleep' and the popular 'Caffeine'. However, none of these apps will stop the Mac from going to sleep once you close the lid (a.k.a. the 'Clamshell' mode).

There is also a utility called [Smart Sleep](http://www.jinx.de/SmartSleep.html) which allows you to set refined preferences to affect your MBP's sleep behaviour and it has an Insomnia plugin. However, this does not work reliably and I would recommend using the standalone InsomniaX instead.